# When trying to run source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm I get a "Badly Placed ()'s" error

Tags: ruby, rvm

I have installed RVM on my machine running Mac OS X 10.8.3 from the tcsh shell.  I am trying to run: `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` in the terminal and I get a `Badly placed ()'s` error.

Any advice?  I looked and this rvm script does exist in the .rvm/scripts subfolder....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when `rvm` defines a function with a name which you have defined as an `alias`. Can you check your aliases which can possibly be a function name that rvm has defined.

The error is not from rvm but from the shell.

As you are using tcsh, there might be some conflict with the function name. Try switching to `bash` and then executing the same.

Comment: forgive me for my ignorance, but how do I go about checking my aliases?

Comment: on the linux prompt type `alias`. Let me know what is the output

Comment: in the Mac OS terminal, alias outputs: username%

Comment: with `set -x` the output is: set: `Variable name must begin with a letter.`

Comment: Which shell are you using? What's the output of `ps -p $$`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30224/discussion-between-ikegawataro-and-draxxxeus)